# Proving that $\mathbb{Z_{-}} \cap \mathbb{N}=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, axioms, peano-axioms

In assumption that $\mathbb{N}$ and successor function ($\overline{x}$) over $\mathbb{N}$ is defined by 5 Peano axioms:

1. $1\in\mathbb{N}$
2. $n\in\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \overline{n}\in\mathbb{N}$
3. $\nexists n\in\mathbb{N}:\ \overline{n}=1$
4. $\forall n,m,k\in\mathbb{N}:\ (\overline{n}=k\land\overline{m}=k)\ \Rightarrow\ n=m$
5. $\left[P(1)\land\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ [P(n)\Rightarrow P(\overline n)]\right]\ \Rightarrow \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ [P(n)]$

and an addition operation is defined over $\mathbb{N}$ by:

1. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad n + 1 = 1 + n = \overline{n}$
2. $\forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}\quad n+\overline{m}=\overline{n+m}$

and that we have proved some base properties of addition over $\mathbb{N}$ like existence, uniqueness and commutivity, we are extending $\mathbb{N}$ and operations to new set (called $\mathbb{Z}$) by including a neutral element (denoted by "$0$") where:
$$\tag{1}\label{d:zero}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\quad n+0=0+n=n$$
*and we know that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$, because if $0\in\mathbb{N}$ then by substitution $n=1$ to \eqref{d:zero}:
$$0+1=1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \overline{0}=1\quad\text{(and that one contradicts 3rd Peano axiom)}$$
and by constructing negative numbers $(-n)\in\mathbb{Z}_-$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by relation $n+(-n)=0$.

So the question is **how to prove that constructed set $\mathbb{Z}_-$ is not already in $\mathbb{N}$?** Maybe there is a simple prove for $(-1)$ which I can extend to other numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $-x \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $0 = x + (-x) \in \mathbb{N}$ (because $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition). But as you already showed, $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Contradiction!

Comment: The problem is to show that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition only by Peano axioms.

Comment: Is it? That's quite easy to do from the definition OP provided, and indeed the statement "... we have proved some basic properties of addition over $\mathbb{N}$ like existence, uniqueness ..." makes me think that OP already has a proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition.

Comment: @Zerox The sum between two elements of $\Bbb N$ was defined recursively on $\Bbb N$ way before introducing everything else. So either the definition made sense before (and proof of that fact was given at the appropriate moment), or one shouldn't have defined the other stuff to begin with.

Comment: @Gae. S Thanks for correcting my statement!

Comment: Oh, that is really nice prove, thanks you!
@Zerox, yes, we are proving that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition before by fixing one operand and using indunction from 1 for second.